# Python how to use the word class to reference a key 'class'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3, how do I reference a key named 'class':

```
print("id: " + eachasset.id)
print("name: " + eachasset.SName)
print("status: " + eachasset.status)
print("class: " + eachasset.class)  # <-- gives me error: Invalid Syntax
```

Spyder 4 highlights the word class as purple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.something` isn't a key, it is an attribute. You cannot use a key-word, like `class` in an expression `some_object.some_attribute` since key-words are reserved.

This was likely set dynamically, so your only option is to retrieve it dynamically, so:

```
getattr(eachasset, 'class')
```

Or just change the name to `class_`, as you would conventionally do to name attributes and avoid using a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```py
print("class: " + getattr(eachasset, "class"))
```